# What's the best way to format/customize the remote response?

Tags: loopbackjs

Sometimes, we need to modify the response JSON data before it be sent to client. for example:

```
//model definition
{
  "name": "File",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "properties": {
    "filename": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "filepath": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
  "protected": ["filepath"]
}
```

I want to get a `url` property on GET `/files/:id` request, and so I defined a url GETTER on prototype.

```
//file.js

module.exports = function(File){
  var baseUrl = 'http://example.com/uploads/files/';
  File.prototype.__defineGetter__('url', function(){
    return baseUrl + this.id.toString() + this.filename;
  });
}
```

My question is How to expose the `url` property to remote response when I make a request as following?

```
GET /files/123456
```

expect a response like:

```
{
  id: '123456',
  filename: 'myfile.ext',
  url: 'http://example.com/uploads/files/123456/myfile.ext'
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's a REAL BAD question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Operation Hooks](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-loaded) to intercept CRUD actions independently of the specific method that invoke them.

The code below will add the `url` property to the File object when loading a File object.

```
File.observe('loaded', function(ctx, next) {
  var baseUrl = 'http://example.com/uploads/files/';
  ctx.data.url = baseUrl + data.id + data.filename;

  next();
});
```

This will get called when any of the methods below are invoked, either directly in your JS or indirectly via the HTTP API.

- find()
- findOne()
- findById()
- exists()
- count()
- create()
- upsert() (same as updateOrCreate())
- findOrCreate()
- prototype.save()
- prototype.updateAttributes()

Other Operation Hooks include:

- access
- before save
- after save
- before delete
- after delete
- loaded
- persist

Comment: Consider adding a bit more explanation to your answer, rather than just making a code-only post. It would probably be a lot more helpful to the OP and future readers.

Comment: @Serlite happy now? :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use a remote method/hook and customize your response accordingly. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-app-logic/blob/master/common/models/car.js.